# Which version of fluentui/office fabric UI is best to be incuded in SPFX project?

Tags: spfx, fluent-ui

The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration) states that by default Fabric core styles are already included in the SPFX framework.

They also say we can use `office-ui-fabric-react`, but that will be included in the output bundle (latest version is 7)

This also has been refactored into `@fluentui/react` package, starting from V8.

Beside direct import in my own `package.json`, `@microsoft/sp-component-base`, which is in the dependency tree, already reference `office-ui-fabric-react`, but stick at `7.180.0`.

So we have three options to include fluent UI react :

- take the same than already included in the dep tree: `office-ui-fabric-react@7.180.0`
- take the latest `office-ui-fabric-react` : `office-ui-fabric-react@^7.185.7` (at this time)
- take the latest `@fluentui/react` to have the very latest version : `@fluentui/react@^8.68.3`

What is the best/recommended/supported version of fluent ui to include ?

Does sticking on 7.180.0 may limit bundle size, hopefully because SharePoint already has loaded it, and webpack take it as an external ?

If not, is there any issue to move to @fluentui/react ?